# VSCode - How to uninstall themes that can't be found by searching '@installed @category:"themes"'

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I have some themes that can't be found by searching:

`@installed @category:"themes"`

And I don't think they come built-in.

How to uninstall those themes?

[image: VS Code theme listing]

Actual theme names typed here for easier searching:

```
PowerShell ISE
Quiet Light
Solarized Light
Abyss
Kimbie Dark
Monokai
Monokai Dimmed
Red
Solarized Dark
Tomorrow Night Blue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I want to address that these themes you mentioned are all **built-in**.

To remove those themes from coming to the list, go to Extensions and type `@builtin`, then disable the unnecessary themes.

[image: built-in themes]

Comment: Good to know this `@builtin` searching criterion. A little bit surprised there are built-in...

Comment: @zerox without build-in themes VSC would be very bland out of the box